# Is there any way to make the following sql query work?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to create two tables using the following SQL:

```
create table student(sid char(20) primary key,name char(20),age int,hours char(10) references courses(cid));                     

create table courses(cid char(10),cname char(10),grader char(20) references student(sid));
```

However I get the following error:

> 1: ERROR:  relation "courses" does not exist
>   3: ERROR:  relation "student" does not exist

Is there any way or syntax which can solve this problem?

Comment: Create the tables without the foreign key constraints. Then create the constraints. You'll need to make at least one of the constraints DEFERRABLE because you have a circular reference. Also the courses table is missing a primary key.

Comment: Incidentally, a few comments on your schema: it's quite unusual to use `char` columns; you probably want `VarChar`, which won't pad out the string with spaces; you have inconsistent naming, `student` singular but `courses` plural; and the meaning of a column called `hours` referencing a `courses` table is somewhat opaque - don't be afraid of longer column names; and you probably want some of those columns to be declared `Not Null`.

Comment: @sqlvogel There may not be an issue with circularity, as both columns currently allow nulls; whether that's intentional or not, I couldn't say, and if it's not, you are right about Deferrable.

Comment: @IMSoP Good point about nulls. Nullable foreign keys are an abomination.

Comment: Having a FK from student to course means that each student can only be assigned to exactly one course - hardly realistic. I would guess you actually want a M:N relation between the two tables (and naming the FK column `hours` seems like a very bad choice as well)

Comment: @sqlvogel cid is primary key for table courses. This is example from the DBMS textbook by Ramkrishnan and Gehrke. The intention of problem is just to know how one can build circular reference.Please don't comment on meaning of the table arguments. I am beginner for DBMS. Can anyone suggest the reference for the solution.

Comment: @mahesh, did you try the solution I suggested in my first comment? I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for a reference for.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating the Foreign Key constraints at the same time as the tables with the `References` short-hand, you can add one or both of them afterwards with an `Alter Table Add Constraint` command. [See the `Alter Table` page in the PostgrSQL manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)

As mu pointed out, the target of a foreign key has to have a `Unique` or `Primary Key` constraint defined, so I've added that on the `cid` column in the example below.

In your case, it could look something like this:

```
create table student(sid char(20) primary key,name char(20),age int,hours char(10));                     
create table courses(cid char(10) primary key,cname char(10),grader char(20));

Alter Table student Add Constraint fk_student_hours_cid Foreign Key (hours) References courses(cid);
Alter Table courses Add Constraint fk_courses_grader_sid Foreign Key (grader) References student(sid);
```

Comment: Your ADD CONSTRAINT syntax is wrong and you can't have an FK to that `courses.cid` column anyway as there is no unique constraint on `cid`.

Comment: @muistooshort Well, it wasn't me that left the `Primary Key` constraint out, it was the OP, but you're right that it will cause an error, so I've added it in. As for the syntax, I'll admit it was from memory, and I find SQL syntax particularly unmemorable; does it look right now?

Comment: You need to name the constraint: `alter table t add constraint c foreign ...`. It usually takes me a couple tries to get the constraint syntax right too, I've internalized the CRUD side of SQL well enough but I don't use the DDL side of things nearly enough.

Comment: @muistooshort Oh, right, it turns out the name *is* optional, but only if you also omit the word `CONSTRAINT`... The `ALTER TABLE` statement in SQL seems to be complete spaghetti, and not even properly standardised. Can we rip it up and start again please? `;)`

Comment: @IMSoP: Not sure what you are complaining about: the format of the `ALTER TABLE` *is* defined by the standard, it's fully documented in the Postgres manual and Postgres follows the standard. The `<table constraint definition>` consists of the optional `<constraint name definition>` followed by the element `<table constraint>`. The element `<constraint name definition>` is defined as `CONSTRAINT <constraint name>` which means that the keyword `CONSTRAINT` is part of the name definition, not part of the `ADD`part.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, it was more of a whinge about it being non-intuitive than a rational complaint (*why* does the keyword `CONSTRAINT` introduce the name and not the whole constraint definition?) As for standardised, this part may be, but much isn't, and `ALTER COLUMN` statements for instance are pretty un-portable in my experience. I also find the massive syntax summaries in the PG manual quite hard to follow, although I'm not sure what a better approach would be; it doesn't help that this one requires you to also read part of the `CREATE TABLE` syntax.

Comment: For the `ALTER COLUMN` part the standard basically only defines setting or dropping a default value - nothing else. That's why every DBMS has a different syntax. The syntax diagrams used in the Postgres manual (and many others like Oracle or DB2) are a widely established standard on how to document this kind of things - and I don't think there is a better way to do that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, like I say, it wasn't really a criticism of PG or its manual as such. I guess the problem is that SQL doesn't have a very consistent "meta-structure", so you *have* to follow the details of the syntax diagrams rather than glancing to get the general idea. As for the standard, it seems to only partially overlap with real usage; e.g. indexes are apparently "an implementation detail", but SQL/PSM is a standard which no-one really implements.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create the tables first (without REFERENCES clause). After that create your foreign keys manually by statement ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT mytablefk FOREIGN KEY... But first I'd consider if there really is a relationship from table courses to table student!